# How to uncompress separated tgz files?

Tags: tar, gzip

I am receiving this error message when I'm trying to uncompress a `.tgz` archive:

```
$ tar -zxvf OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

As you can see, the file name ends with `.tgz.1`.

When the file name is `.tgz.0` it will be uncompressed with no error by the `tar -zxvf` command.

Comment: Why not rename it?

Comment: Is this file splitted?

Comment: I had rather run `file OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1` to see what exactly it is.

Answer (score 14):

This is what I found after a quick google search, [a PDF explaining how to correctly extract the contents of the file](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16538_01/ovm/acrobat/EBusinessSuiteOVMDeploymentGuide.pdf&ei=trPRULqNE5Di9gS4i4DYDA&usg=AFQjCNFx3pqN4kl5NwJfoCYbPJFmxySftA&sig2=5_nBJMjtDKGyAHaL2p4clg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&cad=rja).

Looks like there are several files:

```
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.0
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.2
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.3
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.4
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.5
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.6
OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.7
```

You need to copy all those files to a specific directory, for example `/OVS/seed_pool/`. Then run the following commands:

```
# cd /OVS/seed_pool
# cat OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.0 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.2 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.3 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.4 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.5 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.6 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.7 | tar -xz
```

Note that those are only 2 commands, denoted with the starting `#`.

Those commands shall create the following directory structure, with these files inside:

```
/OVS/seed_pool/OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM
|
|- System.img (OS image file)
|- ebs1211db.img.img (Oracle E-Biz 12.1.1 DB Tier image file)
|- vm.cfg (VM configuration file)
|- README.txt
```

For more help, please look into the PDF mentioned above.

Comment: You don’t have to list all the files manually, a wildcard `*` or `?` would automatically list them in the alphabetical order, so `cat OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.* | tar -xz` should suffice. (You can test the behavior with `echo OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.*`.)

Answer (score 4):

The `tar.gz/tgz` file you are having is split into multiple files. (tgz.0, tgz.1,tgz.2 etc..)

So that's the reason when you try to extract using the command

```
tar -zxvf OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.0
```

it works properly. But the contents wont be fully available.

Use the `cat` command to combine all the OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.* parts into one tar.gz file

then use the command

```
tar -zxvf OVM_EL5U3_X86_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz
```

Comment: Creating a temporary file is not necessary and might be unfeasible if the archive is too big. See [my answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179740/250300) for solutions without temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

These two commands didn't work:

```
$ cat OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.* |  tar zxvf - 
stdin: not in gzip format\ntar: Child died with signal 13\ntar: 
Error is not recoverable: exiting now\ncat: write error: Broken pipe\n’, None
```

---

```
$ cat OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.0 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1 \
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.2  | | tar -xz  `
cat: OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1 No such file or directory\ncat:
 OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.2
```

This worked for me:

```
$ cat OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.0 OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.1 
OVM_EL5U3_X86_64_EBIZ12.1.1_DB_VIS_PVM.tgz.2  | tar -xz`
```

The difference was just using a space instead of `\`.

Comment: Dont' blame line continuation backslash as an alternative to space, as it must not have any significance. Instead, note that you have double pipe `cat ….tgz.2  | | tar -xz` in the second command, which attempts to pipe `cat` output into an empty command before finally passing it to `tar` — that is usually a syntax error and should not even have started at all.