# What is tar -xvf

Tags: tar

I am learning about the basics of Linux and archiving/compressing TAR files i have stumbled across `tar -xvf` and was wondering what it does. I have checked the man pages and know that `x` means extract and `v` means verbose but what does `f` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uncompress separated tgz files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230602/how-to-uncompress-separated-tgz-files) kasper_341's answer

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html Under "device selection and switching"; also the [-f ARCHIVE] in the usage lines are a good hint. See also [how to search within a man page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20752/how-can-i-search-within-a-manpage) or view the man page on the web and use your browser search feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip .tgz file using the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499807/how-to-unzip-tgz-file-using-the-terminal)

Answer (score 9):

As the man page says, `-f` or `--file=` defines the ARCHIVE file from which to extract. It's in the chapter 'Device selection and switching' (line #561 in my version).

Answer (score 6):

`-f` option in tar means that the next argument is the name of the target tar file. So after the `-f` option you can't place another option, for example the following syntax is wrong:

```bsh
tar -xvf --verbose file.tar # Incorrect
```

The following variants should be correct:

```bsh
tar -xvf file.tar --verbose 
tar -xv --verbose -f file.tar
```

Comment: It might be interesting that, depending on your implementation and version of tar, and/or whatever option parsing library it uses, `tar -xfv` may or may not work.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1283/57213 `"-f" tells tar that the next parameter is the file name of the archive or STDOUT if it is "-"`

Comment: Hi, @JörgWMittag, consider `tar -xfv` is not `tar -xf -v`.

Answer (score 5):

`-xvf` is the short (unix style) version of

`--extract --verbose --file=`

As a new tar user one useful option to learn is `-t` (`--test`) in place of `-x`, which lists to the screen without actually extracting it.

`-tvf`