# How to extract *.tgz.part-*?

Tags: tar, gzip

I have several files as follow :

```
multiview_action.tgz.part-aa  
multiview_action.tgz.part-ab
...
...
multiview_action.tgz.part-ap
```

I tried the following command :

```
tar -zxvf multiview_action.tgz*
```

I got the following error :

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Fin prématurée rencontrée dans l'archive.
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 23):

You should concatenate (`cat`) the split tar-gz files, decompress them (`gunzip`) and extract the tar archive (`tar -x`).

You can extract split `.gz` archives directly using the [`zcat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zcat.1.html) command which concatenates and directly uncompresses the files. Then pipe the result to the tar extract command, creating no intermediate files:

```
zcat multiview_action.tgz.part-* | tar -x
```

Another option (with a different grouping of the 3 mentioned commands) is to use `cat` piped to `tar` with the `z` option:

```
cat multiview_action.tgz.part-* | tar -xz
```

Answer (score 7):

Files are divided with [split](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html), to join the file you need to use cat before you can extract your .tgz file:

```
cat multiview_action.tgz.part-* > multiview_action.tgz
```

If you leave out -z from options tar will guess archive type by the file .ext:

```
tar -xf multiview_action.tgz
```

Comment: Creating a temporary file is not necessary and might be unfeasible if the archive is too big. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179740/250300) for solutions without temporary files.

Comment: true if you don't intend to save the original archive.